# Why does collect_list in Spark not use partial aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, aggregation

I recently played around with UDAFs and looked into the sourcecode of the built-in aggregation function `collect_list`, I was suprised to see that `collect_list` does not have a `merge` method implemented, although I think this is really straight-farward (just concatenate two Arrays). Code taken from `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.collect.Collect`

```
override def merge(buffer: InternalRow, input: InternalRow): Unit = {
 sys.error("Collect cannot be used in partial aggregations.")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no longer the case, as [SPARK-1893](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18932) but I'd assume that the initial design had mostly `collect_list` in mind.

Because `collect_list` is logically equivalent to `groupByKey` the motivation would be exactly the same to avoid long GC pauses. In particular map side combine in `groupByKey` has been disabled with Spark [SPARK-772](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-772):

> Map side combine in group by key case does not reduce the amount of data shuffled. Instead, it forces a lot more objects to go into old gen, and leads to worse GC.

So to address you comment

> I think this is really straight-farward (just concatenate two Arrays).

It might be simple but it doesn't add much value (unless there is another reducing operation on top of it) and sequence concatenation is expensive.